# Vercel: A project file dynamically changing for each domain?

Tags: deployment, next.js, web-deployment, vercel

I am building a project on Vercel, deployed to multiple subdomains. The code should be 99% the same, but I need to have a different `manifest.json` for each subdomain.

**Is there a way to make the `manifest.json` file dynamic, based on the subdomain the user visits?**

I thought perhaps [NextJS rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) could help, but I am not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to serve `/manifest.json`, but at least I can return a JSON file from a NextJS Serverless function at `api/manifest` like so:

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
return res.send(manifestJSON);
```

Comment: How did you use this function? keep in middleware?